# Trying to understand ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Tags: python, django

My specific question is, how do I fix this import error so that I can run the python manage.py runsever command?

For some reason my environment did get deleted and I was not pleased about that but when I reinstalled everything I had these issues.

I have searched on stack overflow articles and come up empty.

So far I have:

I asked chat gpt what a python enviornment variable is:

The PYTHONPATH environment variable in Python contains a list of directories where Python looks for modules and packages to import. It allows you to specify additional directories that Python should search when importing modules.

It went on to say run pip install django. Which I have done, I also activated my virtual enviornment.

How do I see my python environment variables? How do I add Django to it?

Any advice?

https://github.com/strikeouts27/mysite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently pip list is a command I can run to see if Django is in my environment. It seems Django is in the list of things it has.

I ran into it again, and I decided to remove my virtual environment and set it up another way that I am more familiar with. it seems to work but I hope it does not cause problems down the line.

python -m pip install django and that worked.

It seems that the way to view this is to ask why pip or whatever is installing it is not installing it.

Comment: apparently python -m pip install django is a better command to run for these instances.

Comment: apparently python -m pip install django is a better command to run for these instances.
the way to look at these errors is to ask why the installer is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s better to create new venv than try to copy lib from global (don’t know is it possible btw).

1. Create venv `python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`
2. Activate venv `venv\scripts\activate` for windows. `venv/bin/activate.sh` for Linux.
3. Now you should see (venv) in green in your console.
4. Well, now you can `pip install django` into your venv. If this doesn't work, use `python -m pip install django`.

Hope this answered your question.